# How to process two forms in one view?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have two completely different forms in one template. How to process them in one view? How can I distinguish which of the forms was submitted? How can I use prefix to acomplish that? Or maybe it's better to write separate views?
regards
chriss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd use one view to handle each form's POST.

On the other hand, you could use a hidden input element that indicate which form was used

```
<form action="/blog/" method="POST">
    {{ blog_form.as_p }}
    <input type="hidden" name="form-type" value"blog-form" /> <!-- set type -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

... 

<form action="/blog/" method="POST">
    {{ micro_form.as_p }}
    <input type="hidden" name="form-type" value"micro-form" /> <!-- set type -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

With a view like:

```
def blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['form-type'] == u"blog-form":   # test the form type
            form = BlogForm(request.POST) 
            ...
        else:
            form = MicroForm(request.POST)
            ...

    return render_to_response('blog.html', {
        'blog_form': BlogForm(),
        'micro_form': MicroForm(),
    })
```

... but once again, I think one view per form (even if the view only accepts POSTs) is simpler than trying to do the above.

Answer (score 4):

like ayaz said, you should give unique name to form submit button

```
<form action="." method="post">
......
<input type="submit" name="form1">
</form>


<form action="." method="post">
......
<input type="submit" name="form2">
</form>


#view

if "form1" in request.POST:
    ...
if "form2" in request.POST:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two forms are completely different, it will certainly not hurt to have them be handled by two different views. Otherwise, you may use the 'hidden input element' trick *zacherates* has touched upon. Or, you could always give each `submit` element a **unique** name, and differentiate in the view which form was submitted based on that.